# Does anybody know where to find a guide to javascript debugger information?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am new to debugging javascript.

When I pause on breakpoints and hover over different variables, I am overwhelmed by the amount of data that is exposed and I cannot understand most of what I am looking at.

Does anybody know about any literature that explains this data?

Any recommended sources would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend asking this on programmers exchange.

Comment: Maybe this is suitable https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Would be cool if you could provide an example, but I assume that the data you see are properties of objects. They have nothing to do with debugging but with the data your processing.

Comment: @MikeCheel Literature requests are off topic on P.SE (P.SE has the same close reason this question was closed with).  The best approach to ask this question *might* be a screen shot and then asking about specific parts of the screen.  Note that programming tool questions are off topic on P.SE (and on topic on SO).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use console.log method and others like this. I like this documentation that explains how to use Chrome Console: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Take a look on these also:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

Comment: So you are suggesting to use `console.log` instead of breakpoints? Why? And how does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: JavaScript browser debuggers exposes a lot of data that aren't 'public' making it difficult to find data we are manipulating. Also, debugging on browsers isn't as easy as it is on an IDE. So I still prefer console.log